# Swagger UI - Unable to see discriminator "type" possible values in documentation UI

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I am trying to get the possible values `Conversion` and `Analysis` to show up in the schema when viewing the API documentation in swagger UI. This is part of my response where I return an object of type `Task` which contains a field called `data` that can be one of 2 possible types.

Right now I just see the property `type` marked as required and of type `string`. as shown in the photo below.

[image]

This makes it hard for someone using the API to figure out exactly what the type string would be set as when the response returns. The actual responses are serialised in the correct format, just the documentation is incomplete. Below is my code:

```
public class TaskOutput {
    
    private TaskDataOutput data;

    @JsonProperty("data")
    @Schema(name = "data", oneOf = {
            AnalysisTaskDataOutput.class,
            ConversionTaskDataOutput.class
    })
    public TaskDataOutput getData() {
        return data;
    }

}

public class AnalysisTaskDataOutput implements TaskDataOutput {

    private Boolean cleanup;

    @Schema(name = "cleanup")
    @JsonProperty("cleanup")
    public Boolean getCleanup() {
        return cleanup;
    }

}

public class ConversionTaskDataOutput implements TaskDataOutput {

    private Boolean converted;

    @Schema(name = "converted")
    @JsonProperty("converted")
    public Boolean getConverted() {
        return converted;
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AnalysisTaskDataOutput.class, name = "Analysis"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConversionTaskDataOutput.class, name = "Conversion"),
})
public interface TaskDataOutput {
}
```

I tried using an Enum containing the Analysis and Conversion values and defining a `DataType getType()` method on the interface, but nothing shows up in the Swagger UI.